# Is there a way to have complete control of your EBS volume snapshots?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227791/why-cant-i-see-my-ebs-volume-snapshots-in-s3-from-aws-management-console) I have learned that they are stored on s3 but we can't see them.

My questions is really asking if there is a way to stored them elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EBS snapshots are backed by S3 but not in a bucket that your account has access to. They can't be accessed directly via S3.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish? No there is not a way, that I know of, to store them somewhere else, and why would you want to? S3 is cheap and redundant, and easy to restore from.

S3 might have some performance blights, but only when you are trying to do something it is not intended for.